# Displaying alternate text for a taxonomy term in node

Tags: theming, nodes

I have a taxonomy term called 'price'. I'd like it to display on the node page if it exists. But I don't want the taxonomy value to appear on the node page, I want the label to appear 'Price:' followed by hard-coded text that says 'see website.'.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

I don't want to use String Overrides because I'm using the value for the taxonomy term elsewhere. Perhaps some sort of code-based method (no pun intended) would work better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the display your theme **node.tpl.php** template. Place something like this in your **template.php**...

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
   $variables['price_display'] = '';
   if(isset($variables['node']->field_terms[LANGUAGE_NONE]) && is_array(($variables['node']->field_terms[LANGUAGE_NONE]))) {
     foreach($variables['node']->field_terms[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $tag) {
        if(isset($tag['taxonomy_term']) && $tag['taxonomy_term']->name == 'price') {
          $variables['price_display'] = 'see website';
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

At this point you should have the variable `$price_display` available to print out in **node.tpl.php**.

Comment: thanks. The logic seems intelligible. But I can't see that deep into the node variable to see the field_terms you're referencing. Can you explain your code to me? This code as is (replacing price_display with field_price) gives no errors but seems to change nothing. When I dpm() I can't see into the node variable you're referencing. The only variable I can see that needs changing is $vars['field_price'][0]['taxonomy_term']->name...not sure where to go from here. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, the nested if/foreach/if is just making sure there's a node object with a field property array it can loop through to look for taxonomy objects with the term name "price". There's probably a better way to do that I'm just going off the idea that there are many node types that may not have the same structure (thus many different structure checks).

Comment: If you can `dpm()` your way into the node var, you should be able to figure it out what you're looking for inside the taxonomy field you're using. Once you've done that you can set `$variables['price_display']` so you can reference it in your node template.